# How to call same epic in parallel?

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm unable to trigger the same epic with different configuration.

I'm developing a web application that contains widgets on each screen. Each widget starts to fetch some data from a different api. You can configure each screen to have different widgets, but also widgets of the same type. In the configuration of a widget you define the url mapping, and on load it fires an action which starts the api fetching with an epic.

If there are different widgets on my screen (i.e. they trigger different epics), everything works fine. But if I configure my screen to contain multiple instances of the same widget (i.e. they trigger the same epic with different url mapping), only the last widget is making actually the call.

It seems that only one instance of an epic can exist and the last rendered widget overwrites the previous epic triggers.

I cannot create separate epics for the different widgets, because they are generated dynamically and each of them should use the same epic.

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem or do I miss on something?

Comment: Looks like you should use `mergeMap` instead of `switchMap`. But could you provide example code?

Comment: @OlesSavluk You just saved my day! I should read more documentation. Thanks!